cosmos openc3 delete default demo example
using https://github.com/OpenC3/cosmos I'm trying to build a github actions to test some features using cosmos openc3 as a frontend.
It has as default a demo example that is running in background with some logs and error conditions. I'd like to remove that from the default deployment to focus all logs only on my project. Suggestions?
what I've done:

in the repo root there is the .env file with the variable that I commented out:
# Comment this variable to disable installing the Demo (don't set it to 0) OPENC3_DEMO=1 ----> #OPENC3_DEMO=1 ----> anyway the demo is running after ./openc3.sh start

official docs https://docs.openc3.com/docs/getting-started/gettingstarted explains:
Before creating your own configuration you should uninstall the COSMOS Demo so you're working with a clean COSMOS system. Click the Admin button and the PLUGINS tab. Then click the Trash can icon next to openc3-cosmos-demo to delete it. When you go back to the Command and Telemetry Server you should have a blank table with no interfaces.. running the app (website) and then uninstalling is not the ideal situation I'd like to use.



Commenting out the OPENC3_DEMO=1 env variable is the correct solution. I'm not sure if you have a separate project env file but that works when running locally. If you output the ENV vars set in the github action you can confirm what is set.
